# Not accessing the value of global variable in Event listener?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a velocity calculator. The problem is that when I am trying to access the value of the input field from  a variable Like  `let d = document.querySelector("#distance").value;` through click event, it is returning as an empty string and the other thing I did is that I changed the input field to number and converted the value directly to `let d = Number(document.querySelector("#distance").value);` and tried to access this it is returning as NAN even though I remove the Number() method

> How it is working properly

it is working properly when I am getting the value of input field  in an event listener and storing it in a variable, So I want to know why is not accessing the global variable value in an event listener

Below are accessible and not accessible code

```js
let d = document.querySelector("#distance").value;
let t = document.querySelector("#time").value;
let v = document.querySelector("#velocity")
let answerBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-answer")
let form = document.querySelector(".listener")


answerBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  // var a = d/t
  // console.log(Number(a))
  console.log(d)
})
```

```css
*,::before,::after{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body{
box-sizing:border-box;
font-family:roboto;
}
.input-value-wrapper{
  border: 2px solid red;
  width:100%;
  padding:12px;
  background:#74b9ff;
}
h1{
  letter-spacing:3px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}
p{
  font-size:21px;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  font-weight:900;
}
.input-container{
 width:50%;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  padding:5px;
  background:#fff;
}
#velocity{
  margin-top:6px;
}
form{
display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
input{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  font-size:21px;
  width:10ch;
}
.btn-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin-top:12px;
}
.btn-answer,.btn-start-drive{
font-size:24px;
  width:120px;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="whole-container">
  
    <div class="input-value-wrapper">
      <div class="input-container">
        <h1>Hello to phycalc() veiwers</h1>
    <p>here you can visualize your calculations isn't cool</p>
      <form class="listener">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Distance" id="distance">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Time" id="time">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Velocity" id="velocity">
        
        </div>
      </form>
        
        <div class="btn-container">
        <button class=btn-answer style="background:#00b894;">Answer</button>
      <button class="btn-start-drive">Start</button>      
        
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="move-car-screen">
<!--    <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3301/3301611.svg" alt="hello"> -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
// Accessible code

let d = document.querySelector("#distance");
let t = document.querySelector("#time");
let v = document.querySelector("#velocity")
let answerBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-answer")
let form = document.querySelector(".listener")


answerBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  let f = d.value
  let g = t.value
  let check = f/g
  
  console.log(check)
})
```

Comment: Move the getting of the values INTO the click function using them

Comment: Also use document.getElementById since they have IDs.

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Also I suggest you move the answer button into the form and use the form submit event instead of the button click event

Comment: `d` was only ever been evaluated when the program initially run, so it's going to `''` for the entire time.

Comment: @mplungjan I wanna know why it is not working is there any case-sensitivity and I have searched for this question but didn't get the right answer

Comment: @Keith can you elaborate your answer

Comment: In the first snippet, you are assigning the value of an input to variable `d`. If the input is still empty, `d` will be an empty string. In your second snippet, you are assigning the input (not its value) to `d` and only access its value later, after you entered some value.

Comment: @derpirscher what do you mean by hte

Comment: @mplungjan Sir can you please please make a glance on my other question that what's the problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433538/settimeout-animation-problem-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment119191753_67433538 it seems complex

Comment: @Keith can you please answer my other Javascript question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433538/settimeout-animation-problem-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment119191753_67433538 it seems complex